# Seaborn boxplot for classification with pandas wide to long

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have data that I would like to train an ml classifier on. The data is in wide format. I'd like to do a boxplot with searborn `sns.boxplot(x='variable',y='value', hue='target', data=df_train)`. How do I reshape the data to be able to pass it to `sns.boxplot`?

Sample data

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=5, random_state=1)
df_train = pd.DataFrame(X)
df_train['y']=y
```

Comment: See https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#messy-data

Answer (score 0):

[pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) is what you want to use.

```
dfg_train = df_train.melt(id_vars='y')
sns.boxplot(x='variable',y='value', hue='y', data=dfg_train)
```